# Configuring Domino Access Services

Tags: lotus-domino

Domino Database and Folder/View present in the database shall be enabled to access documents and views present in domino database.

Manual procedure is mentioned to enable Domino Data services in the documentation.

Is it possible to programmatically enable Domino Data Services for Domino Database and views?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Extension Library](https://extlib.openntf.org/main.nsf/project.xsp?r=project/XPages%20Extension%20Library/summary) REST Services.

Take a look at [Extension Library REST Services.doc](https://www.openntf.org/Projects/pmt.nsf/9D74CA40E5E6BECE862578C40042CA26/$file/Extension%20Library%20REST%20Services.pdf) here you can find information about the four types of REST services which are included in the extension library.

**UPDATE:**

I would prefer to use the Extension Library `xe:restService` service.

If you have installed the Domino Designer you can find it as shown in the screenshot below:

[image]

Comment: Georg thanks for responding to the query. 

I have checked the document you have shared. It contains manual steps to enable Data Access Services for Database and views and folders. 

Are you suggesting me to use other REST services like Custom Database Servlet/Custom Wink Servlet?